# Usage of “so” in “So do I”

Tags: grammaticality

What are the grammatical rules behind the construction using “so” in the following examples?

> A: “I like chocolate.” B: “So do I.”
>
> Alice likes chocolate. So does Bob.

Both examples seem to be correct. But which of the following are correct?

> Alice's car is very expensive and so is her dress.
>
> The flower is nice and so is the garden.
>
> A house is only well-kept if so is its garden.
>
> A house is nice if and only if so is its garden.

In particular, it was suggested to me (by multiple people) to reformulate the last one as:

> A house is nice if and only if its garden is.

So, I am wondering: Is the last example (with the original formulation) actually grammatically wrong or is the suggestion purely stylistic? What are the grammatical rules here anyway?

Also the suggested reformulation sounds a bit odd/not very fluent to me. Would you agree with this feeling? Is there some correct way to express this more elegantly?

I am also interested in regional differences (e.g. British English vs American English) if there are any.

Comment: @PeterShor: That sounds better than the original but is still a bit odd. For some reason, I feel that “A house is nice if and only if its garden is as well” is even a bit more fluent but still… a bit strange to me.

Comment: *Both* of the last two sentences sound wrong to me. (I don't see why the last one is being singled out as more questionable than the second last.) I'm not entirely certain if they are ungrammatical, but they are at least awkward, and I think they would normally be rephrased. (For what it's worth, I believe you can substitute *such* for *so* in those sentences. But while that preserves the meaning, it doesn't help me answer the question about the grammar.) Note that the sense of *so* is different in the earlier sentences —and in which *such* cannot be substituted.

Comment: Having said that, I find the reformulated sentence completely grammatical and natural.

Comment: @JasonBassford: I did not intend to highlight only the last example: I am not sure about any of them (with increasing likelihood of them being incorrect). I tried to make this clearer in the question. I would also appreciate a comment on what you find awkward (if you can nail it down) about the last two and why you say that in the last two you could substitute “so” by “such” but not in the first two (I fail to see a fundamental difference). …

Comment: … For the reformulated version: I don't doubt that it is grammatically correct in any way. I think what strikes me as odd is that the sentences ends a bit abruptly (so it's more like a tiny stylistic/fluency issue). But, if this is not the case for you, then there is probably no problem (I am still interested in whether other people feel what I mean as well).

Comment: I think it's because *so* can only relate to an affirmative clause. Applying that to conditional/hypothetical constructions is not easy, but as a first stab I'd suggest that the two *if* sentences apply whether or not a given house is nice / well-kept, whereas a sentence like *if a house is nice then so is its garden* only applies where it is. In the first type of sentence the proposition *house is nice/well-kept* may be true or false, whereas the second type postulates that it is true - it means *given that the house itself is nice, the garden will also be nice*.